# Trying to figure out why my child theme is trying to access a file that doesn't exist

Tags: css, child-theme

This is my attempt at making a child theme, and everything seems to be working well, however when I view the source code I'm seeing this

`<link rel='stylesheet' id='bootstrap-css'  href='http://wpdallas.com/test/wp-content/themes/Standard/css/lib/bootstrap.css?ver=3.3.1' type='text/css' media='all' />`

which gives me a 404 error. I'm not sure what's going on, and how to fix this....and what problems this could cause me. The site seems to be working fine even with that error. I'm just trying to figure out what it is.

Thanks

Comment: Look in `header.php`. Is that stylesheet link *hard-coded*? If not, it's being *enqueued*. Find (and post) the `wp_enqueue_script()` function call that's being used to enqueue the `bootstrap-css` stylesheet.

Comment: I found this code in the functions.php of the parent theme, is that what you were looking for? `// bootstrap
 wp_register_style('bootstrap', get_template_directory_uri() . '/css/lib/bootstrap.css');
 wp_enqueue_style('bootstrap'); 
 
 // style
`

Comment: That's the one!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From your comment:

> I found this code in the functions.php of the parent theme, is that what you were looking for?
>
> ```
> // bootstrap 
>
> wp_register_style('bootstrap', get_template_directory_uri() . '/css/lib/bootstrap.css'); > 
> wp_enqueue_style('bootstrap');
> ```

1. In your Theme's file structure, do you find `/css/lib/bootstrap.css`? If so, then it should be loading properly.
2. If not, do you find `bootstrap.css` anywhere else in your Theme's file structure? If so, then you should *change the `wp_register_style()` function accordingly, to reference the correct file location*.
3. If not, do you *intend* to enqueue the bootstrap stylesheet? If not, then simply *remove the code entirely*.
4. Another thing: are you using a **Child Theme**? If so, then the Theme is looking for `/css/lib/bootstrap.css` in the **Parent Theme**, due to `get_template_directory_uri()`. If you have the files in your **Child Theme**, change that to **`get_stylesheet_directory_uri()`**.

#### Edit

Also, [the link doesn't return a 404 for me](http://wpdallas.com/test/wp-content/themes/Standard/css/lib/bootstrap.css?ver=3.3.1). I can see the stylesheet, just fine.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. In the parent theme directory there is is a css/lib/bootstrap.css. Yes, I am using a child theme.  I do not have these files in my child theme (this is my first try at making a child theme.) The only thing I have in my child theme folder is http://wpdallas.com/test/wp-content/themes/Standard-Child-Theme-1/style.css do I need to make some changes?

Comment: Right, that link is my child theme css. That's all I have in my child theme folder. However, I'm trying to figure out why I'm getting the error I originally asked about. the css/lib/bootstrap.css error. That link words, but the url isn't ending in .css, it's ending in that strange url thus giving me the 404.

Comment: "*hat link words, but the url isn't ending in .css, it's ending in that strange url thus giving me the 404.*" - that's the link I'm talking about (and the one I linked). It works just fine. I don't get a 404 error, either with or without the version query string.

Comment: Why am I getting a 404 here though? http://wpdallas.com/test/wp-content/themes/Standard-Child-Theme-1/standard_framework/css/standard_framework.css also http://wpdallas.com/test/wp-content/themes/Standard-Child-Theme-1/standard_framework/js/standard_framework.js?ver=3.3.1 and

Comment: No clue; but that's a separate issue from your question, isn't it?

Comment: No, that is the question I was asking. The child theme is trying to access the files....